# Object Not Found Exception in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am really stuck at this error

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.my.farmer.vo.crop.CropProfile#genus]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:145)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:179)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:846)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:557)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:379)
at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:116)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:842)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1851)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2992)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:179)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:846)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:557)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:379)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:584)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:275)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1088)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:689)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:388)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:920)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:405)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:373)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:911)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:903)
at com.my.farmer.dao.impl.MarketDAOHibernateImpl.fetchMarket(MarketDAOHibernateImpl.java:46)
at com.my .farmer.bo.impl.MarketBOImpl.fetchMarket(MarketBOImpl.java:32)
at com.my.farmer.service.impl.MarketServiceImpl.triggerAdvisory(MarketServiceImpl.java:32)
at ClientSpringTester.main(ClientSpringTester.java:26)
```

I have three classes crop, cropprofile and cropspecies.

```
class crop{ cropId(PK), Cropprofile profile id (FK), Cropspecies speciesId(FK)  }  
class cropprofile{ profileid(pk),  genus(unique),  family  }  
class cropspecies{  speciesid(PK), Croprofile genus(FK) }
```

To give you the exact source of error, I have

```
class Marketfeed  {  
Crop cropId,  
Market marketId  }
```

In market feed cropId and marketId are composite key. So, when I do a 
    .find(from Marketfeed market)
this error message error is generated. I am not using any search criteria.

Can anybody suggest possible causes of this error?

Comment: Have you googled or searched SO for that error? There are plenty of sites / pages that describe why you can get the error and the solutions.

Comment: I had. But, couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using `session.load(Object.class,id);` in order to solve this issue you should use session.get(Object.class,id);

Now the explaination:

`Session.load(Object.class,id)` - returns object proxy and in case and this object does not exist it throws the exception you are getting.

`session.get(Object.class,id)` - returns object itself instead od its proxy, if this object does not exist null returned.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are trying to load does not exist in the database by the primary key that you are specifying.

Comment: Yep. The primary key specified is "genus".

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated the code. hope it gives you a better picture

Answer (score 0):

> `class crop{ profile id (FK), speciesId(FK) }`

This sounds like you have references to the ids in your entity, whereas you should have references to Objects:

```
@Entity
public class Crop{

    @ManyToOne // or @OneToOne
    private CropProfile profile;
    @ManyToOne // or @OneToOne
    private CropProfile profile;

    // getters and setters omited
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean @ManyToOne. This is not related to the exception the OP is getting, though.

Comment: @JBNizet a) thanks b) if his code looks like his pseudo-code, he has the IDs as fields, not the entity classes. And that would explain all kinds of errors. Just checking

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked the classes and the IDs are entity classes..Is it related to lazy loading? Just checking